# Not to allow clicking on a div just below another div using Z-INDEX does not work on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have 2 divs in my HTML as shown below. The .show div is right on top of the .hide div.

I want to be able to not allow operating(I mean different events like mouseover and mouseout should not trigger) Dojo Tree widget within the .hide div. My aim is to disable the Dojo Tree widget using Z-Index property. This seems to work fine on Chrome and Firefox but does not work on IE(I have the latest version). I am not able to click on the widget in chrome and Firefox(Which is what I want).But IE still allows me to operate with the widget although there is a div on top of it.

I did try the eventlistener method to fix this issue but it did not help.

```
<div>
    <div class="show" style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;width:200px;height:200px;"> 
        <!--This div is empty-->
    </div>
    <div class="hide" style="height:200px;height:200px">   
        <div id="Testing" dojoType="camiant.form.SingleCheckBoxTree"
                        store="store"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.Thanks a lot...

Comment: What is the css class of `show`?

Comment: Are you making the parent `div` be the relative for the absolute position? . Must be another elements or CSS properties works fine this way for me http://jsfiddle.net/J9jc2/ tested on chrome ie9 and firefox

Comment: @R3tep:I did not get your point. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Danko:The entire section of html code above is within a <td></td> of a HTML table. Both the divs(.show and .hide) overlap each other. My code works fine on Chrome and Firefox. But it does not work fine in IE 11. Any ideas???

Comment: Sorry. The css code of `show` class*

Comment: @R3tep:style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;width:200px;height:200px;"

Comment: can you share an example? in jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y976x/2/          I am not able to click on the checkbox because of the z-index(On chrome). But if you try this on IE you will be able to click on the checkbox which is what I dont want.

Answer (score 1):

Why you not use the css property `display:none` ?

Code :

```
<div class="hide" style="height: 200px; height: 200px; display: none;">   
    <div id="Testing" dojoType="camiant.form.SingleCheckBoxTree" store="store"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to hide the .hide div. I want it to be displayed on the page without being able to click on it.